# Have a table named TEST with 3 columns. 2 columns has big queries as a cell value. I want to update the column data using reg expression in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
~Test_num  ~src_qry      ~tgt qry
---------------------------------------
~123       ~sql query1    ~sql_query2
~124       ~sql query3    ~sql query6
~125       ~sql query4    ~sql query7
~126       ~sql query5    ~sql query8
```

sql query: it is a Oracle sql query(testing queries stored in table.), used to test data in the table(joins, sub queries are used.  ex: customer, relation, transaction and partition_table is used)

change: if partition_table is used in queries of src_qry and tgt qry column, then partition_table.frequency column condition from should be removed from the query.

Output:
as a res
ult i want to check which record is using partition_table.frequency column, if column is used in src_qry and tgt qry column, then i need to remove that condition data( by removing frequency='D' or  frequency='M').

before update(sample):

```
select c1,c2 from T1
leftjoin t2 on t2.c1=t1.c1
and t2.part_num=(select part_num from *abc.partition_table pt where pt.frequency='M' and type_code='cp'* )
where t1.c3='xyz'
and t1.part_num=(select part_num from *xyz.partition_table pm where type_code='cp' and pm.frequency='M'*);
```

after update:

```
select c1,c2 from T1
leftjoin t2 on t2.c1=t1.c1
and t2.part_num=(select part_num from **abc.partition_table pt where  and type_code='cp'**)
where t1.c3='xyz'
and t1.part_num=(select part_num from **xyz.partition_table pm where type_code='cp'**);
```

How to handle this kind of updates.

Can anyone help on this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think of **replacing** those conditions with `1=1` as

- it is always true
- you don't have to worry what's in front of strings to be replaced (is it `where` or `and` and what will happen if you just "remove" those conditions, e.g. you might get

  ```
  where and type_code='cp'

  where type_code='cp' and);
  ```

  which are both invalid.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select q'[
  3  select c1,c2 from T1
  4  left join t2 on t2.c1=t1.c1
  5  and t2.part_num=(select part_num from abc.partition_table pt where pt.frequency='M' and type_code='cp' )
  6  where t1.c3='xyz'
  7  and t1.part_num=(select part_num from xyz.partition_table pm where type_code='cp' and pm.frequency='M');]'
  8     from dual
  9    )
 10  select regexp_replace(col, q'[p.\.frequency='M'|'D']', '1=1') result
 11  from test
 12  where instr(col, '.frequency') > 0;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select c1,c2 from T1
left join t2 on t2.c1=t1.c1
and t2.part_num=(select part_num from abc.partition_table pt where 1=1 and type_code='cp' )
where t1.c3='xyz'
and t1.part_num=(select part_num from xyz.partition_table pm where type_code='cp' and 1=1);


SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot,  you gave good suggestion to replace with 1=1 condition, it  avoids some complication. i'll try  this method.      Thanks for your suggestion/idea..

Comment: Hi littlefoot,  want to write code which applies to all rows( 2 column ) in a table. 
 ~Test_num  ~src_qry      ~tgt qry
---------------------------------------
~123       ~sql query1    ~sql_query2
~124       ~sql query3    ~sql query6

Comment: You'd use lines #10 - 12 in my example. Instead of TEST table, you'd use your table name. Instead of COL column name, you'd use your own column names. You'll have to repeat the same code (REPLACE) for all columns involved.

Comment: Hi littlefoot,  if table has 100 records, then for all 100 records need to check  frequency column is used or not in src_qry and tgt_qry column.  if frequency column is used,need to replace that condition with 1=1 .      I can list all data which is using frequency column like below.
select * from abc.test
where (src_qry like '%frequency%' and tgt_qry like '%frequency%')

 I need to replace frequency='M'|'D']' with '1=1' for all result set for above query.

Comment: here in this line "  regexp_replace(col, q'[p.\.frequency='M'|'D']', '1=1') result  "    how to make it as case incensitive.(for both upper and lower cases)

Comment: By reading REGEXP_REPLACE documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm); one of its parameters can be `'i'` which makes it case-insensitive.

Comment: Handled case sensitivity. need to match pattern match for 2 more conditions. 1. for table alias may or may not present (pt.frequency='M',frequency = 'M').   2.single space before or after = sign (pt.frequency='M',frequency = 'M').  single space before or after = sign.  how to make changes  in  lines #10 - 12.